# MySQL query handle undefined

Tags: php, mysql

I have the following code, which works fine. Queries are executed, everything is OK. BUT I am getting a error from PHP: `Notice: Undefined variable: handle in ..../class.database.php on line 43`.

I can not figure out why that is happening.

(Line 43 points to the line of code marked below)

```
function __construct($hostname, $user, $pass, $databasename)
{
    $this->$handle = mysqli_connect($hostname, $user, $pass);
    if(!$this->$handle)
    {
        $this->seterror();
        return false;
    }
    $handle = mysqli_select_db($this->$handle, $databasename);
    if(!$handle)
    {
        $this->seterror();
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}

function query($text)
{
    $result = mysqli_query($this->$handle,$text); // LINE 43
    if(!$result)
    {
        $this->seterror();
        $this->geterror(); // temp
        return false;
    }
    return $result;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

handle should be a property of your class declared with "public", "private" or "protected" keyword. You should not use "var" to declare property specially if you are using recent version of PHP.

Like it was said before. If you declare the property properly, you will have to change

> $this->$handle to $this->handle

to make it work.

Answer (score 2):

Using dollar sign for class property is unnecessary,
You can change `$this->$handle` to `$this->handle`

```
function __construct($hostname, $user, $pass, $databasename)
{
    $this->handle = mysqli_connect($hostname, $user, $pass);
    if(!$this->handle)
    {
        $this->seterror();
        return false;
    }
    $handle = mysqli_select_db($this->handle, $databasename);
    if(!$handle)
    {
        $this->seterror();
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}

function query($text)
{
    $result = mysqli_query($this->handle,$text); // LINE 43
    if(!$result)
    {
        $this->seterror();
        $this->geterror(); // temp
        return false;
    }
    return $result;
}
```

Comment: I do know that, however I was trying to fix the following error thrown by a different line `Warning: Use of undefined constant handle - assumed 'handle' (this will throw an Error in a future version of PHP)`

Comment: Make sure you have defined the handle in your class, like `private $handle;`
https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_oop_classes_objects.asp

Comment: it is defined as `var $handle;` (could that be the problem eventually?)

Comment: @Illya unfortunately not, too long, too complicated, that's why I provided the relevant lines..... however, I have solved it by now, no idea how....